# Showing a set of matrices is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $M_n$ be the set of $n\times n$ real matrices, identified with $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the usual way. Let $U \subset M_n$ be the subset $$U = \{ X \in M_n | I-X \text{ is invertible} \}$$

Show that $U$ is an open subset of $M_n$ and it contains $V = \{X | \ ||X|| < 1\}$ where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm.

So far the only way I have managed to come up with is to show that $M_n$ is complete, then "Guess" the inverse of $I-X$ as $I+X+X^2+\cdots$ then show that this converges when $||X|| < 1$ so $V \subset U$. Then use this to prove that the set of invertible matrices is open and then apply the homeomorphism $f(X) = I-X$ to show $U$ is open.

As you can see that is very complicated, this question is just one small section of a longer question designed to be done in 30 minutes so I am probably missing a much easier way of solving the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is invertible if and only if the determinant in nonzero.

Comment: The map $X\mapsto \det(I-X)$ is a continuous function, so the preimage of an open set is open.  $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open, so ...

Comment: Yes, and how do I show the determinant is continuous?

Comment: It's polynomial in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch:

- If we write 
  $$
  X=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}&\dots&x_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_{n1}&\dots&x_{nn}\end{bmatrix},
  $$
  then 
  $$
  \det(I-X)=\det\begin{bmatrix}1-x_{11}&\dots&-x_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\-x_{n1}&\dots&1-x_{nn}\end{bmatrix}
  $$
  is a polynomial in the $x_{ij}$'s (use the cofactor/symmetric group expansion) so the determinant is continuous in the entries of the matrix $X$.  Hence the preimage of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is an open set (and the open set is $U$).
- For the second part, note that $I-X$ is not invertible is the same as $X$ has an eigenvalue of $1$.  The condition that $\|X\|<1$ implies that all eigenvalues of $X$ have norm less than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant function is continuous. But observe $U$ is the set $\{X \in M_n \mid \det(I - X) \neq 0\}$, which can be written $\det^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})+I$, which is an open set.

Comment: Isn't $\det^{-1}(\{0\})$ a closed set, do you mean the complement of what you have?

Comment: My mistake, I'll edit.